# Target Image Not Working

Tags: image, target

I'm tying to get a simple hover to b/w function on an image but am not having any luck. I gave it an id of pw but the css still won't target it. Any suggestions?

See for img of the code (http://i120.photobucket.com/albums/o176/DaRR2121/coding_zpsae973137.png)

*Edit*

Realized the pic was too small.

Here's the partial code: http://jsbin.com/ohudey/1/edit

Comment: Does that edit mean you figured it out?

Comment: Nope :p Just thought it would be easier for you guys to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you gave your image `id="pw"` but in your CSS you have `.pw`. Change your `.pw` to `#pw`. In CSS, `#` signifies an id. `.` signifies a class. If you change that for both the normal and hover attributes your code works just fine.